# String or double to byte

Tags: java, parsing, byte

I have a problem. I receive a `double` val=80.22. Then I split it:

```
String[] arr=String.valueOf(val).split("\\.");
int[] intArr=new int[2];
intArr[0]=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); // 80
intArr[1]=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); // 22
```

Now i need to put this values into a `byte[]`. But I don't need the value into the `byte[]`, I need it like this: 0x80 , 0x22.

What I have tried:

```
byte firstbyte = Byte.parseByte(arr[0], 16);
byte secondbyte = Byte.parseByte(arr[1], 16);
```

This works fine but only to the value 80, then I receive:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"80" Radix:16
```

But I don't get it. I need the number up to the value 100.

I have tried to write it into a string like string = 0x80 but I don't know how to put it into the `byte[]` then.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"I receive a double val=80.22"* + *"i need it like this: 0x80 , 0x22"* = `String result = "0x" + String.valueOf(val).replace(".", ", 0x");`

Comment: `System.out.println(0x80);` would show you that `0x80` is 128 decimal. The range of a byte is `-128` to `127` in Java.

Comment: 80 base 10 is not 80 base 16. Your logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bytes are signed in Java.  The highest value in a `byte`, in hexadecimal is 7F, so 80 is too big.  Unfortunately there is no `parseUnsignedByte`.

The workaround is to use the type with the next higher range up, a `short`, then cast the result back to `byte`.

```
byte firstbyte = (byte) Short.parseShort(arr[0], 16);
byte secondbyte = (byte) Short.parseShort(arr[1], 16);
```

This will turn "80" into `-128`, but the byte representation is correct: `1000 0000`, or 80 in hexadecimal.

Note that if the `short` value is out of the range of even an unsigned byte (at least 256, or "100" in hexadecimal), then this will silently truncate the value to the least significant 8 bits, i.e. 256 -> 0, 257 -> 1, etc.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much, now i get it!

Answer (score 1):

Its hard for me to understand the question, but if you want to put a number up to the value 100 in a byte data type you just need to write:

```
    byte firstbyte = (byte)intArr[0];
    byte secondbyte = (byte)intArr[1];
```

Because 0x80 is an hexadecimal value and its worth to the decimal 128 which is too big for that data type.

Answer (score 0):

byte max value is 2^7 - 1 = 127 in dec.

0x80 is hex representation of 128 in dec.

Hex counts from 0 to 9 then from A to F.

So, 80 in dec will be 0x50.

Simply avoid second parameter in Byte.parseByte() or use Byte.valueOf("80")